# Uniqueness of a stationary measure for a simple ODE

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

1. How to prove uniqueness of the stationary measure using coupling approach to the following process: $u_{n+1}=S(1)u_n+\eta_{n+1}(\omega)$, where

a) $S(1)y_0:=y(1)$, $y(t)$ solves the following Cauchy problem
$$
y'(t)+y^3(t)-y(t)=0, y(0)=y_0.
$$
b) $\eta_n$ - i.i.d. random variables with proper finite moment (exponential?).

2. Could someone suggest literature on random processes generated by ODEs and PDEs covering such questions.